# Xdebug command line client will not run to breakpoint

Tags: xdebug-3

I am unable to get the Xdebug command line client working https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgpClient.  The client appears to connect OK but will not run to a breakpoint.  I am trying to debug WordPress in Docker.  First I use `breakpoint_set` then `run`.  Then I try and navigate in my browser to the WordPress page which has the breakpoint but the browser is stuck loading on the homepage.

With exactly the same WordPress, Xdebug and Docker setup I can debug with VSCode just fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I too am interested in this. Strangely if I tell VSCode to break on all exceptions that does work, but not in the "user code".